# Web Apps to display only certain web app items

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

Imagine we have a Web App that has a dropdown field called `Location` with the options Melbourne, Adelaide, Sydney etc.

It is possible to create a new Page with the Web App module on the page to display only the items that have the web app items that have the option "Melbourne" selected?

As in I only want to output only the web app items that have the Melbourne option selected onto the page. All of the other items (ones with Adelaide selected, Sydney selected etc.) to not display on the page? It should not even be in the source code either.

Is something like this possible with Liquid? I wished I knew more Liquid!

Because at the moment all I am doing is just:

```
{module_webapps id="123456" filter="all"}
```

And then just `display:none;` on the items I don't want to appear on the page, but this is not really ideal because even though you can't see it on the page, it can still be read in the source code.

I know this is possible using Classifications and then displaying the module with the classification but I do not want to use this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this on the [Adobe BC Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2010501) but for others who may find this via Google, here is the answer:

You can do something like that with if statements in Liquid.

This is the concept:

```
<!-- Web App code, change to fit your needs (such as sortType, number per page, etc.) -->

{module_webapps id="123456" filter="all" resultsPerPage="500" sortType="date" collection="location" template=""}

<!-- FOR LOOP TO LOOP OVER THE COLLECTION -->

{% for i in location.items -%}

  {% if i.['Location'] == 'Melbourne' -%}

      <!-- Now only web app items with the Location set to Melbourne will show below. -->

      <!-- Code for your web app item, for example:-->

      {{i.name}} - {{i.['Location']}}

  {% endif -%}

{% endfor -%}
```

Of course, you do not have to use a collection, you could put the if statement in any layout and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new "Locations" web app with items Melbourne, Adelaide, Sydney etc, and instead of using dropdown fields in your current web app (let's call it "Cherries") you use data source fields to the new Locations web app.

Then your current page would be the Locations web app detail page, availing the name of whatever item you're viewing by {{name}}. The code would look like this:

```
{module_webapps id="Cherries" filter="all" collection="cherries" template=""}
{% for item in cherries.items -%}
  {% if item.Location_name == {{name}} -%} {% comment -%} You could also use itemid instead of name here) {% endcomment -%}
    ...do something...
  {% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
```

This way you only write the code once in the detail page, and you don't have to hard code the list values in the custom web app fields or hard code various if statements.